# Spark - sample() function duplicating data?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to randomly select a subset of my data and then limit it to 200 entries. But after using the `sample()` function, I'm getting duplicate rows, and I don't know why. Let me show you:

```
DataFrame df= sqlContext.sql("SELECT * " +
        "                     FROM temptable" +
        "                     WHERE conditions");
DataFrame df1 = df.select(df.col("col1"))
        .where(df.col("col1").isNotNull())
        .distinct()
        .orderBy(df.col("col1"));
df.show();
System.out.println(df.count());
```

Up until now, everything is OK. I get the output:

```
+-----------+
|col1       |                                                                                                                                                                           
+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10016|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10022|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100281|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10032|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100427|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100445|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10049|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10070|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10076|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10079|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10081|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10082|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100884|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10092|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10099|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10102|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10103|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101039|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101134|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101187|                                                                                                                                                                           
+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                           
only showing top 20 rows 

10512
```

with 10512 records without duplicates. AND THEN!

```
df = df.sample(true, 0.5).limit(200);
df.show();
System.out.println(users.count());
```

This returns 200 rows full of duplicates:

```
+-----------+
|col1       |                                                                                                                                                                           
+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10022|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100445|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     100445|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10049|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10079|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10079|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10081|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10081|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10082|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10092|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10102|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10102|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101039|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101134|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101134|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101134|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101345|                                                                                                                                                                           
|     101345|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10140|                                                                                                                                                                           
|      10141|                                                                                                                                                                           
+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                           
only showing top 20 rows                                                                                                                                                                

200
```

Can anyone tell me why? This is driving me crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly ask for a sample with replacement so there is nothing unexpected about getting duplicates:

```
public Dataset<T> sample(boolean withReplacement, double fraction)
```